# What is the most Oracle compatible open source DBMS?

Tags: oracle, open-source, database

My organization is thinking on using an open source DBMS (free if possible, but not mandatory) for all new apps that we develop. Since we already have quite a few apps that connect to an oracle server, we would like to use a DBMS that is as compatible as possible with Oracle. So we can port the apps to oracle with the less work in the case we don't get the same performance or just don't like how it responds. Also, most of the developers have experience only with Oracle.

Which one would you recommend? We're trying to cut down costs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Postgresql has always proven to be a good choice in my experience.

Read up on [Oracle to Postgres conversion](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion)

There is also [this page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL) which offers links to more information and tools for migration.

Specifically the [Porting from Oracle PL / SQL section](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-porting.html) of the PostgreSQL manual.

Comment: The referenced page appears to be ancient, though. The phrases "Postgres large objects are scheduled for a major overhaul in summer 2000" and "However, with the lztext extension coming with Postgres 7.0" indicate that any conversion advice on this page should be considered suspect.  I agree with the recommendation of PostgreSQL, just not the instructions on the referenced page.

Comment: +1 Agreed. I have included some links to more recent sources of information that will hopefully help.

Answer (score 4):

[PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196207/what-is-the-most-oracle-compatible-open-source-dbms) is probably the only open source enterprise class DBMS and the syntax resembles more of PL/SQL than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely **not** MySQL. They are as similar as pickles and wool socks.

Use postgres. I suggest this resource:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_for_Oracle_DBAs

Comment: +1 just for "pickles and wool socks".  Spot on info as well.

Comment: In the light of the recent acquisition of Sun it will be interesting to see how this changes in the coming years.

Answer (score 3):

Probably [Postgres Plus Advanced Server](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/postgres_plus_as/overview.do).

Comment: This one seems like a very good alternative. However, I understood that the extensions for making compatible are not open source. Am I right?

Comment: I... don't actually know. This is what Google came up with >.>

Answer (score 0):

why not Oracle's Berkeley 11g? I bet it offers best integration with Oracle.

Comment: Berkeley DB is key-value DB, not a relational DB like PostgreSQL or MySQL.